# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'subcat_id2' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'subcat_id2' at row 1 .this is the problem i am getting and sql query is [my sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNKPt.jpg)

And ths is the my admin panel looks like when i add a product 
[this shows when i add product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tynxB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `indexing` WHERE subcat_id2 = 1
```

Comment: still getting an error  - insert into indexpg set cat_id='1',subcat_id='4',subcat_id2='',color='2',opening_image='2',title='awd',alt_tag='asd',samp_price='254',org_price='235',price='7',disc='awdawdaw',featured='0',status='',code='IWM-009',paper='wdwad',size='awd',weight='67',title1='wadwad',title2='wdad',title3='awd',title4='awdwa',title5='dwad',image1='',image2='',image3='',image4='',image5='',imgpath='94banner3.jpg',rsvp_price='20',mtyou_price='25',puroity='0',mkey='wdaa',mdisc='adwad',vid=''Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'subcat_id2' at row 1

Comment: subcat_id2='' (in the query above) doesn't have a value but it must have because it has an integer type! subcat_id2='1' should work.

Comment: The above things didn't work. I can't see any subcat_id2 between subcat_id1 and color when I go to add a product. Is this could be a problem? Help me!